# How to configure Geoserver WMS to make it printable from QGIS/ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, geoserver, wms, printing

I have installed geoserver 2.3.1 - I am using this to create a WMS of some data held in PostGIS.
I can view the WMS in QGIS and ArcGIS, but it won't print from ArcGIS (blank sheet) and in QGIS I get the message:

Some WMS servers (e.g. UMN mapserver) have a limit for the WIDTH and HEIGHT parameter. Printing layers from such servers may exceed this limit. If this is the case, the WMS layer will not be printed

So I assume I have to set something in Geoserver or on the server to allow larger print sizes - where can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/24086

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alefren's [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62518/geoserver-set-maxmimum-width-height-for-printing#comment83847_62518) helped me solve this issue.

I increased the memory allocations in the WMS to 0 (max) as described in the [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geoserver.user/24086) in the comments but that did not solve the issue.

I am running TomCat on Windows. So I increased the memory allocation, by going to:

`Programs>> TomCat 6.0 >> Configure TomCat`

Under the Java tab I increased the memory until the print would work at A3 - for me the value was 2048MB.